# Show that the full null space of the matrix A and its column space in the plane 2x+2y - z = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Show that the full null space of the matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&5\\ 1&0&0 \\ 2&2&10 \end{bmatrix}$ is the line $\lambda$(0.-5,1), $\lambda \in \mathbb R^3$ and its column space in the plane 2x+2y - z = 0

For nullity it's just me row reducing for leading ones trying to show as much as i can that x,y,z=0 . Obviously x=0 from row 2 hence nullity is a least one.

So i row reduce it...
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&5 \\ 1&0&0 \\ 2&2&10 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&5 \\ 0&2&10 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&5 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$$

so $x_3=t, \, x_1=0, \, x_2 =-5t$ which proves the null space of A is the line $\lambda = (0,-5,1) \in \mathbb R^2$?

How do i show that its column space  the 2x+2y-z = 0?

Comment: For equations satisfied by the column space, you have to row-reduce and solve for the equations defined by the transpose matrix.

Comment: How do i show that its column space  the 2x+2y-z = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the equation(s) of the column space (which is the range of the associated endomorphism of $\mathbf R^3$),  you have to solve for the system:
$$\begin{cases}a\cdot 0+b\cdot1+c\cdot2=0\\a\cdot 1+b\cdot0+c\cdot2=0\\a\cdot 5+b\cdot0+c\cdot10=0 \end{cases}$$
Written matricially, it becomes:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&2 \\ 1&0&2 \\ 5&0&10\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus the matrix of the system is but the transpose of the given matrix. We row-reduce this matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2\\1&0&2\\5&0&10\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&2\\5&0&10\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
and we obtain the solutions: $\;a=-2c,\enspace b=-2c$, so that $\; \begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\\c\end{bmatrix}=-c\begin{bmatrix}2\\ 2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, whence the equation:
$$2x+2y-z=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

So i row reduce it...
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&5 \\ 1&0&0 \\ 2&2&10 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&5 \\ 0&2&10 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&5 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$$

so $x_3=t, \, x_1=0, \, x_2 =-5t$ which proves the null space of A is the line $\lambda = (0,-5,1) \in \mathbb R^2$?

How do i show that its column space  the 2x+2y-z = 0?